# Is there something similar to collide_points for Vertex Instructions in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

The Widget [collide_points](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.collide_point) allows to identify if an event that occurs inside a widget.

I know that one approach used in the [Pong Game example](http://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/pong.html#add-the-ball) is putting the vertex instructions that we want to collide inside a Widget. In the Pong Example [the ball](http://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/pong.html#add-the-ball) is a Widget that has an Ellipse in its canvas. The problem with the this approach is that internally the ball is actually a rectangle (not an issue for this particular game).

I was wondering if there is any implementation that indicates if a coordinate (x,y) is inside a particular Vertex Instruction.

I know there are some maths involved so I don't really expect Kivy handling this yet. However, I guess any other library could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There isn't something like this in Kivy*, but you should check out some of the examples that are bundled in Kivy. There is one called [customcollide](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/widgets/customcollide.py) that implements "*Custom shape & collide widget*".

Comment: So the answer is there is not something like that in Kivy. I actually ended implementing something similar to this but I was wondering if there was a library/package with the maths included. Thanks for pointing to the example. That confirms what I thought.